# Change form action with prototype

Tags: forms, prototypejs, action

how can I change a form's action with prototype ? I've seen plenty of examples with jquery using:

```
 $("#form1").attr("action","http://actionurl.com");
```

but haven't one with prototype. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [writeAttribute](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/writeAttribute) method:

```
$('form1').writeAttribute('action', 'http://actionurl.com');
```